# Team capacity pulled from rally using rallyRest API is not matching with the figure shown in CAAC

Tags: java, rally

Very recently i started with a code to integrate rally data to our application by pulling the rally data using `rally-rest-API-2.2.1` jar. I could pull almost all the data needed, but when I pull the team capacity of the current sprint the figure I get is entirely different from the one which I can see in CAAC tool. I get all the values shown in the CAAC tool added with some extra capcaity values.

Could anyone help me to pull only those capacity shown in the CAAC Tool UI.

```
QueryRequest capacityRequest = new QueryRequest("UserIterationCapacity");
         List<String> fetchCapList = new ArrayList<String>();
         fetchCapList.add("Capacity");
         capacityRequest.setFetch(new Fetch(fetchCapList.toArray(new String[fetchCapList.size()])));
         capacityRequest.setProject(projectRef);
         capacityRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Iteration.Name", "=", jsonResp.get("Name").getAsString()));
         QueryResponse capQueryResponse = restApi.query(capacityRequest);`
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your query filter is matching iterations with the same name in other projects.

Can you instead scope it exactly to the iteration and project you're interested in?

```
capacityRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Iteration", "=", jsonResp.get("_ref").getAsString()));
```

Comment: I tried by disabling the Project scope, but no change in the capacity value pulled from rally.

Comment: Hmm, I guess it's possible that endpoint does not respect project scoping.  Are you getting any warnings in your response?

Comment: Thanks for the code. I tried to provide the same iteration name and project name. but still it gives me the extra capacity values which we don't see in UI. But I did some research came to know that these capacities are of those resources who are not part of the project, but assigned with some project task and capacity.